# Is there a document loading rate limit on Bluemix Discovery service

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

We are switching to the new Discovery service from the Retrieve and Rank service on Bluemix.  This requires quite a bit of code rewrite and I'm getting a strange error message while transferring our answer units to Discovery:

```
Error: The service is busy processing 20 of your documents. Please wait for some of the documents to complete, then try again.
```

Is there some kind of rate limit on inserting documents into Discovery?  If so, how do we increase or better, eliminate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a rate limit for inserting documents into Watson Discovery. Larger environment sizes have higher rate limits, but every size does have a limit.

**Background**

The big difference between sending a document into Retrieve and Rank compared to Discovery is that sending a document into Retrieve and Rank is synchronous but sending a document into Discovery is asynchronous.

Retrieve and Rank will not respond to an API call to index a document until the processing is complete. Discovery responds as soon as the document has been accepted into the pipeline for processing and processing is likely to take several seconds to complete.

Discovery limits the number of documents in the processing pipeline per service instance and returns a `429` status when the limit is exceeded.

Retrieve and Rank has what amounts to the same kind of restriction: limiting the number of concurrent requests for a single service instance.

Comment: I don't remember ever hitting a limit in RandR, and we've pounded answer units into it as fast as we can retrieve them from Cloudant, albeit usually in 100-AU blocks.  What would be the "best practice" algorithm for adding documents to Discovery through the API as quickly and efficiently as possible? This may be a bigger rewrite than I thought.

Comment: The goal is to keep your pipeline reasonably full within Discovery. I've used two approaches. The simpler one is just _push fast_ until I see a 429, then sleep a while, then go back to _push fast_ again. The more complex one is to repeatedly ask Discovery for document status for each document, until you see the document succeed (or fail) and do that in as many concurrent threads as your Discovery in-flight limit. In any case, always retry (typically after sleeping) after a 429. (Maybe this answer should go in the my main answer or a separate SO question.)